# What is the python keyword "with" used for?

Tags: python

What is the python keyword "with" used for?

Example from: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

```
>>> with open('/tmp/workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

Comment: It’s handy when you have two related operations which you’d like to execute as a pair and you need the execution of both of them to be guaranteed no matter how the nested code in between them might exit. See an example here: https://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/

Comment: Since I think that Fredrik Lundh's explanation is still one of the best, and since effbot.org is now "on hiatus" -- here's one of the snapshots from archive.org: [http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm](http://web.archive.org/web/20180310054708/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Answer (score 637, accepted):

In python the `with` keyword is used when working with unmanaged resources (like file streams). It is similar to the `using` statement in VB.NET and C#. It allows you to ensure that a resource is "cleaned up" when the code that uses it finishes running, even if exceptions are thrown. It provides 'syntactic sugar' for `try/finally` blocks.

From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement):

> The `with` statement clarifies code that previously would use `try...finally` blocks to ensure that clean-up code is executed.
>
> The `with` statement is a control-flow structure whose basic structure is:
>
> ```
> with expression [as variable]:
>     with-block
> ```
>
> The expression is evaluated, and it should result in an object that supports the context management protocol (that is, has `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods).

*Update* fixed VB callout per Scott Wisniewski's comment. I was indeed confusing `with` with `using`.

Comment: What methods are used to close the open resource?  What if I made my own file system object that had its own special open/close methods, would the "with" keyword work with those?  Or will "with" only work with the built-in Python resource types?

Comment: In Python it looks like the custom object would have to implement (or inherit from something which implements) the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. With IronPython (python on .Net) you can implement from IDisposable and that will cover it. Not sure what is the best way in pure Python or other frameworks.

Comment: FYI: this is confusing the "using" statement in VB.NET, which behaves like the "with" block in python, with the "with" statement in VB which is completely different. See the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 487):

[Explanation from the Preshing on Programming blog](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/):

> It’s handy when you have two related operations which you’d like to
> execute as a pair or more, with a block of code in between. The classic
> example is opening a file, manipulating the file, then
> closing it:
>
> ```
>  with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
>      f.write('Hi there!')
> ```
>
> The above with statement will automatically close the file after the
> nested block of code. (Continue reading to see exactly how the close
> occurs.) The advantage of using a with statement is that it is
> guaranteed to close the file no matter how the nested block exits. If
> an exception occurs before the end of the block, it will close the
> file before the exception is caught by an outer exception handler. If
> the nested block were to contain a return statement, or a continue or
> break statement, the with statement would automatically close the file
> in those cases, too.

Comment: I want to add an additional answer for the use of with in python, not related to opening or close file : 

def test_new_user_invalid_email(self):
        """Test creating user with no email raises error"""
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            get_user_model().objects.create_user(None, 'pass@word')