# Which Python library for file access to analyse and manipulate?

Tags: python

For starters I'm going to make a program which analyses my poker hand histories which are stored automatically as text files.

So which library do I need to snoop around in if I'm looking to analyse .txt files? I mean I can find some functions but I want to become more independent instead of googling a solution each time and actually learning things by myself...tell me if this is a stupid idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do these text files look like? Plain text files can be read using Python's built-in `open()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open()` if its very simple, [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) if its a bit more complicated and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for everything else.

Comment: yes it's plain text.

So if I use open() then f.read() I can save that txt file as a string?

Comment: @Behzad Basically, yes. You'll want to consider using the [with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1369553/264775) keyword, like `with open("file.txt", "r") as someName`, instead of just `open()` - it closes the file properly if things go wrong.