# Scala alternative to pythons `with`

Tags: scala

In python you can avoid try {} catch {} finally {} boilerplate with `with` (see [What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)). I remember seeing an alternative to that in Scala, but I can't find it anymore.

It goes along the lines of:

```
def using[O](r: {def close()})(doit: () => O): O = try {
  doit()
} finally {
  r.close
}

using(myWriter){() => myWriter.println("something or another")}
```

Is it built into 2.10, or do I need a separate library for it?

Comment: Most widely known library for doing this is https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm, and no, AFAIK scala doesn't provide this feature out-of-the-box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost trivial to make your own that covers almost all use cases (here using 2.10):

```
implicit class TidyUpAnything[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def tidily[Z](g: A=>Any)(f: A=>Z) = try { f(a) } finally { g(a) }
}
```

If you want exceptions to pass through, use as is:

```
scala> Option(null: String).tidily(println){_.get}   // Should print None
None
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
    ...
```

and if you want to handle exceptions, use it in conjunction with [scala.util.Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.util.Try):

```
scala> import scala.util._
scala> Try( Option(null: String).tidily(println){ _.get } )
None
res1: scala.util.Try[String] = Failure(java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get)
```

Normally you would make `g` be something like `_.close`, but you can do arbitary resource cleanup with it.  For example, here we back off a counter by one whenever we finish:

```
var i = 0
val a = Array(1,2)
a.tidily(_ => i -= 1){ _.foreach(_ => i += 1) }
scala> i
res2: Int = 1
```

Comment: I came to a similar solution, but I was thinking there should be something out there that already had this. scala-arm seems a compelling alternative to rolling your own.

Comment: @iwein - If you want more than what you asked for, scala-arm is indeed compelling.  For this alone, adding a dependency instead of three lines of code is a strange compulsion.

Comment: point taken. The syntax that you get with scala-arm is arguably nicer than the one you get with TidyUpAnything. I'm somewhat skiddish of adding implicits for generic situations...

Comment: @iwein - You are perfectly free to `def tidily[A,Z](resource: A)(tidy: A => Any)(act: A=>Z) = try { act(resource) } finally { tidy(resource) }` if you prefer a one-liner without implicits.  scala-arm has syntax better tailored for some scenarios, agreed.