# How to close file after request

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
files = {'file': ('output.mp3', open('output.mp3','rb'), 'audio/mpeg')}
```

I am using this for POST request but after usage trying to delete it with os.remove and it gives "it's used by a process". How to close file after?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opening & closing file without file object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070063/opening-closing-file-without-file-object-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with ...`:

```py
import os
import requests

# open the file and send it
with open("output.mp3", "rb") as my_file:
    files = {"file": ("output.mp3", my_file, "audio/mpeg")}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    # ...

# file is closed now, remove it
os.remove("output.mp3")
```