# Python: Auto-correct

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two files check.txt and orig.txt. I want to check every word in check.txt and see if it matches with any word in orig.txt. If it does match then the code should replace that word with its first match otherwise it should leave the word as it is. But somehow its not working as required. Kindly help.

**check.txt looks like this:**

```
ukrain

troop

force
```

**and orig.txt looks like:**

```
ukraine cnn should stop pretending &amp; announce: we will not report news while it reflects bad on obama @bostonglobe @crowleycnn @hardball

rt @cbcnews: breaking: .@vice journalist @simonostrovsky, held in #ukraine now free and safe http://t.co/sgxbedktlu http://t.co/jduzlg6jou

russia 'outraged' at deadly shootout in east #ukraine -  moscow:... http://t.co/nqim7uk7zg
 #groundtroops #russianpresidentvladimirputin
```

http://pastebin.com/XJeDhY3G

```
f = open('check.txt','r')
orig = open('orig.txt','r')
new = open('newfile.txt','w')

for word in f:
    for line in orig:
        for word2 in line.split(" "):
            word2 = word2.lower()            
            if word in word2:
                word = word2
            else:
                print('not found')
        new.write(word)
```

Comment: *"If it does match then the code should replace that word with its first match otherwise it should leave the word as it is"* what should be replaced? in original file or in check file?

Comment: Note if you opens a file in read more using 'r' then can't write in that file.

Comment: `for word in f: for line in orig` If the second loop loops over lines, then what would the first loop loop over?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i have replaces 'r' with 'w' still its not working

Comment: @user3571809 if you replace `"r"` with `"w"` then new empty file will be created.. you can't read from that file. -- so still wrong. Your question is unclear at first, there are many fundamental mistakes as well, I suggest you read some more stuff first on file and basic Python.

Comment: It would help if you provided some example inputs and expected outputs. Now we're just guessing.

Comment: @tobias_k check.txt only has single words on each line but orig.txt has sentences at each line so loops have to be like this

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan now i'm writing in newfile.txt ... still not working

Comment: @user3571809 from your inner most loop it looks your logic is not clear, you are assigning `word = word2` multiple times, Additionally either remove inner-for-loop and just do `word in line` or use `word == word2` if you wants to check exact mach.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i don't want exact matches... i'm trying to replace my stemmed words with the closest word in orig.txt

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan how do i break the loop as after i have assigned word=word2 for the first time... i'm new to python so i'm having difficulty figuring this out

Comment: @user3571809 As I said in my first comment, Please also add your expected output in Question.

Comment: hey as per ur example do u want to replace ukrain with ukraine right??

Comment: check this might be useful https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. when you loop over the words in `f`, each word will still have a new line character, so your `in` check does not work
2. you want to iterate `orig` for each of the words from `f`, but files are iterators, being exhausted after the first word from `f`

You can fix those by doing  `word = word.strip()` and `orig = list(orig)`, or you can try something like this:

```
# get all stemmed words
stemmed = [line.strip() for line in f]
# set of lowercased original words
original = set(word.lower() for line in orig for word in line.split())
# map stemmed words to unstemmed words
unstemmed = {word: None for word in stemmed}
# find original words for word stems in map
for stem in unstemmed:
    for word in original:
        if stem in word:
            unstemmed[stem] = word
print unstemmed
```

Or shorter (without that final double loop), using [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), as suggested in the comments:

```
unstemmed = {word: difflib.get_close_matches(word, original, 1) for word in stemmed}
```

Also, remember to `close` your files, or use the [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for) keyword to close them automatically.