# How to write to consecutive CSV columns in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am writing data from a list to a csv file like this:

```
def writeToCsv(list, max):
    writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=' ')
    for x in range(0,max):
        writer.writerow(list[x]['year'])
```

This fills the first column with the years which is great. Now I want to fill the next column with the 'name' in the list. How can I run the above code again but have it fill the next column instead of writing over the first column with the 'name'?

Comment: When using the `csv` module, you should structure your code so you write one *row* at a time, not one column.  That's why the method is called `writerow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a list to `writerow`:

```
def writeToCsv(list, max):
    writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=' ')
    for x in range(0,max):
        writer.writerow([list[x]['year'], list[x]['name']])
```

Notice you can do this:

```
def writeToCsv(lst, limit):
    # use a context manager to close the file for you when you're done
    with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
        # takes the first `max` dictionaries from the list
        for item in lst[:limit]:
            writer.writerow([item['year'], item['name']])
```

This is using [slicing](http://www.dotnetperls.com/slice) and the [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369553/948550) context manager.

**note:** I've changed the names of the function arguments so that you don't shdow the built-in functions [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max). (thanks @Padraic Cunningham)

Comment: might be worth mentioning and changing the numerous builtin names  that are being shadowed

Comment: This puts both 'year' and 'name' into the same first column

Comment: Just had to change the delimiter to a comma.  Thank you :)