# Unable to perform I/O on a file using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have been trying to open a file and make some edits in it using regular Expressions. The code seems fine but i still get an error saying io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Code is as follows:

```
import re

def fun(o_date):
    print(o_date)
    l = o_date.split('-')
    r=[]
    r[0]='20'+l[0]
    if l[1]=='Jan':
        r[1]='01'
    elif l[1]=='Feb':
        r[1]='02'
    elif l[1]=='Mar':
        r[1]='03'
    elif l[1]=='Apr':
        r[1]='04'
    elif l[1]=='May':
        r[1]='05'
    elif l[1]=='Jun':
        r[1]='06'
    elif l[1]=='Jul':
        r[1]='07'
    elif l[1]=='Aug':
        r[1]='08'
    elif l[1]=='Sep':
        r[1]='09'
    elif l[1]=='Oct':
        r[1]='10'
    elif l[1]=='Nov':
        r[1]='11'
    elif l[1]=='Dec':
        r[1]='12'
    r[2]=l[0]
    r1 = str(r[0])+'-'+str(r[1])+'-'+str(r[2])
    return r1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello 0.1")
    f = open('Finance.sql','w')
    print("hello 1.1")
    r = f.read()
    print("hello1")
    s = re.compile(r'\d{2,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3-3}-\d{2,2}')
    for i in r:
        print("hello : ", i)
        re.sub(s,fun,i)
```

The Finance.sql files just contains insert commands into the table.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You dont call `fun` anywhere here. Please provide complete code.

Comment: Please provide a sample of `Finance.sql` which will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, you are opening a file for writing (`'w'`), and then trying to `read` from it.

Comment: @merlin2011 sorry.. just provided the full code

Comment: @larsks u can perform read on a file opened with a ('w') flag

Comment: No, you can't.  I just tried and received the same error you are reporting.

Comment: @larsks it is generating the error on the read line  r = f.read(). I even tried r=f.readline(). Says same error.

Comment: Yes, and I think we have figured out your problem.

Comment: Did you try changing `w` to `r`?

Comment: @merlin2011 it does work with 'r'. But why? 'w' supports both read and write. correct ?

Comment: Not correct.  To open an existing file for reading and writing, use `'r+'`, as in @syntonym's answer.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line says you want to only write to your file (note the `'w'`):

```
f = open('Finance.sql','w')
```

Opening a file for read and write (non truncated, python3):

```
f = open('Finance.sql','r+')
```

You should use `with` to cleanly open and close the file (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for))

Are you sure you want to open a .sql file in this way?