# How can I recreate a list of list of floats from the contents of a file?

Tags: python, string, list, text, split

I have a text file coords.txt containing lists in separated rows:

```
[0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0, 2.0, 1.0]
[0, 1.0, 4.0]
```

the first column is ID, second and third ones - coordinates.

I want to obtain following effect:

```
[[0, 0.0, 0.0], [0, 2.0, 1.0], [0, 1.0, 4.0]]
```

I try the code:

```
file = open(coords.txt).read()
list = file.splitlines()
```

Result is:

```
['[0, 0.0, 0.0]', '[0, 2.0, 1.0]', '[0, 1.0, 4.0]']
```

The other way I used is:

```
file = open(cords.txt)
list= [line.translate(None, '[]').split('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
```

Result is:

```
[['0, 0.0, 0.0', ''], ['0, 2.0, 1.0', ''], ['0, 1.0, 4.0']]
```

How can I obtain expected outcome (get into the list to change strings to floats)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is in the same format as when a list of floats is printed as a string, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method to convert it back to the actual list, like this

```
>>> import ast
>>> with open("coords.txt") as input_file:
...     result = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in input_file]
...     
>>> result
[[0, 0.0, 0.0], [0, 2.0, 1.0], [0, 1.0, 4.0]]
```

We open the file with the `with` statement, and then read the lines in the file one by one with the `for` loop (`for line in input_file`). We do `ast.literal_eval` on the read lines and the result of the call is stored in the list, with the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You can read more about the with statement, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3012488/1903116), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1369526/1903116) and [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

---

Actual problems with your approaches are,

```
file = open(coords.txt).read()
list = file.splitlines()
```

will just read the entire contents as a single string and then just split the string on the new line characters. But the list will still have only strings.

And when you tried

```
file = open(cords.txt)
list= [line.translate(None, '[]').split('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
```

you have just removed the `[]` characters from the individual lines, and split the line based on `\n`. You still haven't attempted to convert them back to floats. It will still be string only.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong in the answer. I ll try to fix it. If there is a way to improve it, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

For each line in the text file, you first need to get rid of the square braces, then you split the string on `", "` (mid the space here), Then after splitting you get a list of strings then you need to convert those strings to floats, for which you can use `map()` function.

```
data = []
with open("sample.txt", "r") as data_file:
    for line in data_file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()[1:-1]   #To remove the starting and ending braces
        data.append(map(float, line.split(", ")))

print data
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having all floats, you can strip the `[]` and newline then split on commas mapping to float:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    data = [list(map(float, line.strip("[]\n").split(","))) for line in f]
    print(data)
    [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 4.0]]
```

Or using [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to find all the digits:

```
import re
with open("in.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("\d+\.\d+|\d+")
    data = [list(map(float, r.findall(line)))for line in f]
    print(data)

    [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 4.0]]
```

Using translate you would split on `,` after removing the `[]`:

```
 data = [list(map(float, line.rstrip().translate(None,"[]").split(","))) for line in f]
```

Unrelated but you don't need to call readlines, you can just iterate over the file object instead of creating a list with readlines unnecessarily.