# 2 different output from an input file iterated from mmap and read with a chunk in C

Tags: python, c, whitespace, mmap, non-printable

I want to read a file which has some characters in it and check the percentage of printable characters as well as the percentage of white spaces.
This is my Python code which generates the input file:

```
import string
import random
array = list()
array = list(string.printable)
print(array)
external = ['\0','\a','\b','\v','\f','\e']
array = array + external
file = open("in.txt" , 'w')
for i in range (1000):
        outputline = array[random.randrange(0,len(array)-1)]
        file.write(outputline)
file.close()
```

I want my file to have both printable characters and whitespaces and other characters (which are not in these two groups).
I do this in two ways:

1. Read the file, chunk by chunk, with the `read` system call in C:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <ctype.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   int main(int arg, char *argv[])
   {
       char c ;
       char *data;
       int numOfWs = 0 ;
       int numOfPr = 0 ;
       int numberOfCharacters;
       int sizeOfBlock ;
       int nread ;
       int i=0;
       int k;
       float wsP = 0;
       float prP = 0;
       sizeOfBlock = atoi(argv[3]) ;
       data = malloc(sizeOfBlock*sizeof(char));
       int fd = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
       while((nread = read(fd, data, sizeOfBlock)) > 0)
       {
           numberOfCharacters += nread ;
           for (i = 0; i < nread; ++i)
           {
               c = data[i] ;
               if(isprint(c))
                   numOfPr ++ ;
               else if(isspace (c))
                   numOfWs ++ ;
           }
       }
       wsP = (numOfWs / (float)numberOfCharacters)*100;
       prP = (numOfPr / (float)numberOfCharacters)*100 ;
       printf("%d printable characters out of %d bytes, %.2f%c\n", numOfPr,numberOfCharacters,prP,'%');
       printf("%d whitespace characters out of %d bytes, %.2f%c\n", numOfWs,numberOfCharacters,wsP, '%');
       exit(0);
   }
   ```
2. Copy the whole file into memory using `mmap()` and then start to read it from memory:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/mman.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <ctype.h>
   #include <string.h>
   int main(int arg, char *argv[])
   {
       char c ;
       int i, numOfWs = 0, numOfPr = 0, numberOfCharacters = 0;
       char *data;
       float wsP = 0;
       float prP = 0;
       struct stat s;
       int fp = open("x.txt", O_RDWR);
       int status = fstat (fp, &s);
       int size = s.st_size;
       data = mmap((caddr_t)0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fp,0);
       for (i=0; i<size; i++){
           char c;
           c = data[i];
           if(isspace(c))
               numOfWs ++;
           else if(isprint(c))
               numOfPr ++;
           numberOfCharacters ++ ;
       }
       wsP = (numOfWs / (float)numberOfCharacters)*100;
       prP = (numOfPr / (float)numberOfCharacters)*100 ;
       printf("%d printable characters out of %d bytes, %.2f%c\n", numOfPr,numberOfCharacters,prP,'%');
       printf("%d whitespace characters out of %d bytes, %.2f%c\n", numOfWs,numberOfCharacters,wsP, '%');
       close(fp);
       exit(0);
   }
   ```

when I check these two ways with the same file (created by the Python code) I get two different answers for the percentages but the number of characters which are read each way are the same (1000).

This is my file generated from the Python code (I don't know what happens when I copied it here it contains lots of control characters):

```
el*2mlz_XyjP@%?Sw}Qo~.."tJ^~6,eN8+kq l)*N-1oupE
)coFKoA0\=|W'{Oezx~^p(B5ZJe!AdYb{Gflv&wwCf8}>3"v*>9\pW8PIs;qpX7RSk<9}&8B$u kNaq(mJK$N-!38?E%8-T,I1zC~0O=}FH*
x9x6Q%GT_C0j>7:@EG{N ?Eh$?18;Ncy[3 $'ikKs%:A].?e;i4`x"k!VD]}*pw
?\wE~Vix7^H~[26lsN?_GO$vz3M464S`+h=A(5@]q<&<+ hjmehAb-_3*3F8&#iM3p)6T`S9Q\yZwm$U`OHG}02{A)WcVzBR1h}H?qhF:P^-j5AQ1<7FD60j#B#}9Z=}2QReaYy|{Wv<^!yOC/7P}n*ZEPV2@8cU),=*5]]d a:3J;Y(?D?31$pcrquc#&PB;A[9lV+gJ%WZ6K~A|%^E_\3dM/?"y)BtUtG"3hf}W4,3DrXxTyl\UbWwCbMufqCNWx |hiJ\>43S6tCCS)rEo0.cz5PjgK0_AKN|8'g]byLp9AlrZDuK1OX,Csa}nu&i_p,#
Wyc{Q
LA\4:!WSq"ln|Pv.B;+N'h%O;tu(CgIh~OYIXCl+6~nSxBuybP nH:j;t'\vk&p}
,;3Ny#`Ug!rVbqExY|  %BVCD^D~z:L(j8L!    @   X4a!KBNCQ4z&3^9[O<fkM-qrOq5F/M*]yyU+-VLdZRtUu
a"=a b%c~GI|tcC/
P'/`t|hZ/2iHd94l"%;4-{)VUw%%3"e%IQ{RAX]NeMcsh&@LziT0)_T"2XADH&NYqa<6,$wdSp@LIMGA&,Gx1mj|t't?7=YtT77r<qi8;|tzi kOAi'dq%+g2   5hY?XTj{F)18.Vd!!$Q{D)}$7XxO)Vi%29*,P"cXkC,M|&brd&-DGF>V4 %N)a"VM+TQ$FI;YiL-0 YSxXgC@i~,o6/a7U2c"eGr\N7^B:'dytlOOS(iy\lhC7vnW,f o;vKUNa
Hg#u}W4N wUM
```

this is the result from `mmap()`:

```
961 printable characters out of 1000 bytes, 96.10%
39 whitespace characters out of 1000 bytes, 3.90%
```

and this is the result from `chunk reading`:

```
974 printable characters out of 1000 bytes, 97.40%
26 whitespace characters out of 1000 bytes, 2.60%
```

Why is the number of `printable characters` different, but the file is the same in the two methods?

I think `isspace()` doesn't accept  as a white space in chunked mode and instead counts it as a `printable character`.

Comment: You don't need to pass the `'%'` character as a paramter just use `%%` in the format string. I don't understand your question, _I get two different answer ..._ What do you meant?

Comment: I think that the chunk reading does not take space ` ` a white space whrn call the `isspace()`

Comment: @iharob this is [my file](http://pastebin.com/NvsPNQwU) generated from python.the answers of each method is [here](http://pastebin.com/EYxMjBYm) you'll see the differences between answer for a same file

Comment: عماد BTW, don't use `fp` as a file **d**escriptor identifier use `fd`, it doesn't matter but it's confusing, when I read `mmap((caddr_t)0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED,  fp, 0);` I immediately thought "_Oh no, he passed a `FILE *` to `mmap()`_, also be consistent with your coding style.

Comment: @iharob tnx , i edited

Comment: A little style notice for the Python code: use [`with`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1369526/562769) when you open files.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `numberOfCharacters` to `0` in the first program.

That means that the value of `numberOfCharacters` is undetermined before

```
numberOfCharacters += nread ;
```

is executed, this is a good reason to separate declaration from definition.

Comment: I edit what you say both here and in my code but the result is still what i added now in my question.

Comment: @EmadSmart Are you on windows using MinGW or cygwin?

Comment: @EmadSmart don't edit the question in a way that will make my answer invalid.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that spaces are printable in the `isprint()`i change the order of `isspace()` and `isprint()` and use `if()...else if()` it becomes true.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, and of course spaces are printable, I just read that part from the first program, and missed it in the second program.