# How to import other information (columns) from CSV to final written CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am running a csv file through a function that will normalize and standardize addresses. The function creates two csv files: one with a normalize addresses and an error csv file that contains addresses that cannot be normalized. Currently my input csv file runs only the address, city, state and zipcode, but I also want to include name of the business into the input csv file.

How do I add the name field so that it will import the information into the given output csv files? I want that the name appears in all given output files. For example :

Input has ALbert Golf Course, address 
Output should have  Albert Golf Course, Normalized Address

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? What does it do / what should it do?

Comment: Also: You don't need `;` in Python and you should use [`with`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1369526/562769) for opening files.

Comment: There is no problem I am trying to figure out how to import other information like name into the ouput csv files

Comment: So how should my script look like to include the "with". How do I add the other information like name to the output csv files.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by normalized addresses ?

Comment: Just like you did before: `outputRow += whatever + ","`

Comment: what is lob in the python script ?

Comment: @Gonzalo68, just finished writing code for the question you just deleted, you may as well use it http://pastebin.com/L7AqKEQR Not all courses have all fields so that has to be taken into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is

> How do I add the name field (...) ?

Define the row number:

```
address1    = 0
address2    = 1
city        = 2
...
business_name = 5
```

Then add to output:

```
except Exception, e:
    outputRow = row[business_name] + ",".join(row) + "," + str(e)+ "\n"
    ...

else:
    outputRow = row[business_name] + " " + verifiedAddress.address.address_line1 + ","
```

Comment: what is lob in the python script ?

Comment: Did you write the script yourself? [lob](https://github.com/lob/lob-python) seems to be a "python wrapper for the Lob.com API".

Comment: As i learn from the posts on python from stack overflow, so was inquisitive as what exactly is this lob .Anyways thanks, but could you explain what do you mean by wrapper ?

Comment: @salilvishnuKapur I'm sorry, I thought you were the one who posted the question :-) A wrapper is a piece of software which allows you to access code e.g. not natively written for that language, or for example accessing an API like an object. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library).

Comment: No I am modifying and testing it for my own research purposes.