# Python:Matching Regular Expression in file

Tags: python, regex

I wrote the following code in Python to match string inside files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

f = open('file','r')
for line in f:
    mat = re.search(r'This',line)
    mat.group(0)
f.close()
```

I used the following file as input:

```
This is the first line
That was the first line
```

But when I try to search  for the expression `This` it results in `None` output.
Why isn't the string is not matching?

Comment: @stribizhev You don't need that. Also your not printing the results of the `.group(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `with` syntax to make sure files are opened properly.

You didn't check to see if there was a match first so it would crash when it checked the second line. Here is some working code:

```
import re

with open('file','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        mat = re.search(r'This',line)
        if mat:
            print mat.group(0)
```

Comment: what is the difference between the two ways of opening a file??

Comment: @sarthak You don't need to close the file descriptor in this case

Comment: @sarthak It also closes the file if an exception is raised. It is generally considered better. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for

Answer (score 1):

I prefer compiling the pattern beforehand, and use it at each iteration.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'This')

with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        mat = pat.search(line)
        if mat:
            print(mat.group(0))
```