# Understanding the Python 'with' statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand if there is there a difference between these, and what that difference might be.

Option One:

```
file_obj = open('test.txt', 'r')

with file_obj as in_file:
    print in_file.readlines()
```

Option Two:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    print in_file.readlines()
```

I understand that with Option One, the `file_obj` is in a closed state after the with block.

Comment: I... am not sure. Time to fire up a Python REPL session and see if there is a difference!

Comment: These are both examples of contextually opening a file. It basically allows the file to be automatically closed when you are no longer within the context of the file being read/written.

Comment: Not exactly the same questions, but could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for

Comment: Read the docs on [`with` context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). Basically, they're using magic methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`, and it doesn't matter if you call it directly on the object returned by `open` or store it first and then call it.

Comment: @deduplicator the answer in that dupe happens to touch on this in passing, but it isn't a dupe. That question is (like the first dupe) about what gets bound by the `as`. This question is whether an extra intermediate variable stops the context manager doing its thing.

Comment: @Ivc: my answer on the dupe covers that explicitly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't know why no one has mentioned this yet, because it's fundamental to [the way `with` works](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). As with many language features in Python, `with` behind the scenes calls [special methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames), which are already defined for built-in Python objects and can be overridden by user-defined classes. In `with`'s particular case (and context managers more generally), the methods are `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

Remember that in Python **everything is an object** -- even literals. This is why you can do things like `'hello'[0]`. Thus, it does not matter whether you use the file object directly as returned by `open`:

```
with open('filename.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
```

or store it first with a different name (for example to break up a long line):

```
the_file = open('filename' + some_var + '.txt')
with the_file as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
```

Because the end result is that `the_file`, `infile`, and the return value of `open` all point to the same object, and that's what `with` is calling the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods on. The built-in file object's `__exit__` method is what closes the file.

Comment: Does the `__enter__` method for `file` actually do anything at all? The file is opened during `__init__` then closed in `__exit__` - I can't think of anything that `__enter__` would do.

Comment: I believe it simply returns the file object (itself) and does nothing else. [This page (last paragraph)](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) seems to corroborate that.

Comment: Ah, right, it has to `return` that because otherwise the name in `as name` would just get assigned `None`.

Comment: Yeah, the return value from `__enter__` is important, though you might not notice it if the only context manager you use is a file. When you do `with foo as bar`, `bar` may or may not be the same thing as `foo`. It will be whatever `foo.__enter__` returns, which could be something else.

Answer (score 8):

These behave identically. As a general rule, the meaning of Python code is not changed by assigning an expression to a variable in the same scope.

This is the same reason that these are identical:

```
f = open("myfile.txt")
```

vs

```
filename = "myfile.txt"
f = open(filename)
```

Regardless of whether you add an alias, the meaning of the code stays the same. The context manager has a deeper meaning than passing an argument to a function, but the principle is the same: the context manager magic is applied to the same object, and the file gets closed in both cases.

The only reason to choose one over the other is if you feel it helps code clarity or style.

Comment: Actually, that might make difference if there was more (potentially failing) code between `open` and `with`, but in this case even the byte code is nearly identical.

Comment: @bereal in which case, *adding that code* makes the difference, not assigning the variable.

Comment: I think this is a decent answer but like Eli Korvigo in question comments I am surprised you have not mentioned `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods yet. It is actually not at all like your example because in your case, either the string literal or the value of `filename` will be passed to a function and renamed in its scope anyway. This is more like the difference between immediately subscripting the return value of a function `hello()[0]` as opposed to assigning then subscripting `hello_result = hello(); hello_result[0]`.

Comment: @two the workings of the context manager arent actually important here. It *is* the same situation as passing a string literal or a variable to `open`, and both of these are *also* the same as subscripting the result of a function call. In all three cases, adding the extra variable doesn't change the meaning of the code (even though that meaning is quite different between the three cases).

Comment: @lvc Look at the question and the initial response of those who didn't already know the answer. The confusion is whether or not the file object would be closed at the end. With the inlined call everyone was _sure_ it would be closed, because that's just how `with` works. With the pre-created `file_obj`, suddenly everyone's not so sure. But why? Because ultimately it has to do with _that object's_ `__exit__` being called. Your example looks like it's missing the point. It has nothing to do with what's passed to open, and everything to do with what's done to the object it returns.

Comment: @two I've added some mention of this to my answer, but I dont agree that it needs (or benefits from) a discussion of how context managers are implemented. This is fundamental to how Python in general works, and not something perculiar to the `with` statement.

Answer (score 6):

If you just fire up Python and use either of those options, the net effect is the same *if the base instance of Python's `file` object is not changed*. (In Option One, the file is only closed when `file_obj` goes out of scope vs at the end of the block in Option Two as you have already observed.)

There *can* be differences with use cases with a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) however. Since `file` is an object, you can modify it or subclass it.

You can also open a file by just calling `file(file_name)` showing that `file` acts like other objects (but no one opens files that way in Python unless it is with `with`):

```
>>> f=open('a.txt')
>>> f
<open file 'a.txt', mode 'r' at 0x1064b5ae0>
>>> f.close()

>>> f=file('a.txt')
>>> f
<open file 'a.txt', mode 'r' at 0x1064b5b70>
>>> f.close()
```

---

More generally, the opening and closing of some resource called `the_thing` (commonly a file, but can be anything) you follow these steps:

```
set up the_thing                       # resource specific, open, or call the obj
try                                    # generically __enter__
    yield pieces from the_thing
except
    react if the_thing is broken 
finally, put the_thing away            # generically __exit__
```

You can more easily change the flow of those subelements using the context manager vs procedural code woven between `open` and the other elements of the code.

Since Python 2.5, file objects have __enter__ and __exit__ methods:

```
>>> f=open('a.txt')
>>> f.__enter__
<built-in method __enter__ of file object at 0x10f836780>
>>> f.__exit__
<built-in method __exit__ of file object at 0x10f836780>
```

The default Python `file` object uses those methods in this fashion:

```
__init__(...)            # performs initialization desired

__enter__() -> self      # in the case of `file()` return an open file handle

__exit__(*excinfo) -> None.  # in the case of `file()` closes the file.
```

These methods can be changed for your own use to modify how a resource is treated when it is opened or closed. A context manager makes it *really easy* to modify what happens when you open or close a file.

Trivial example:

```
class Myopen(object):
    def __init__(self, fn, opening='', closing='', mode='r', buffering=-1):
        # set up the_thing

        if opening:
            print(opening)
        self.closing=closing    
        self.f=open(fn, mode, buffering)

    def __enter__(self):
        # set up the_thing
        # could lock the resource here
        return self.f

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # put the_thing away
        # unlock, or whatever context applicable put away the_thing requires
        self.f.close()
        if self.closing:
            print(self.closing)
```

Now try that:

```
>>> with Myopen('a.txt', opening='Hello', closing='Good Night') as f:
...     print f.read()
...
Hello
[contents of the file 'a.txt']
Good Night
```

Once you have control of entry and exit to a resource, there are many use cases:

1. Lock a resource to access it and use it; unlock when you are done
2. Make a quirky resource (like a memory file, database or web page) act more like a straight file resource
3. Open a database and rollback if there is an exception but commit all writes if there are no errors
4. Temporarily change the context of a floating point calculation
5. Time a piece of code
6. Change the exceptions that you raise by returning `True` or `False` from the __exit__ method.

You can read more examples in [PEP 343.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between the two - either way the file is closed when you exit the with block.

The second example you give is the typical way the files are used in Python 2.6 and newer (when the `with` syntax was added).

You can verify that the first example also works in a REPL session like this:

```
>>> file_obj = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> file_obj.closed
False
>>> with file_obj as in_file:
...     print in_file.readlines()
<Output>
>>> file_obj.closed
True
```

So after the `with` blocks exits, the file is closed.

Normally the second example is how you would do this sort of thing, though.

There's no reason to create that extra variable `file_obj`... anything that you might want to do with it after the end of the `with` block you could just use `in_file` for, because it's still in scope.

```
>>> in_file
<closed file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x03DC5020>
```

Comment: *there's no reason to create that extra variable file_obj.* What if the code somewhere down the line needed another context manager for that file?

Comment: @BhargavRao anyway, you'll have to re-open that file. `with` won't do that for you.

Comment: You did not get my point. Instead of again doing `with open('test.txt', 'r') as in_file:` the OP can directly do `with file_obj as in_file:`. My argument was towards storing values in variables and not about the context manager. I just wanted to mention that there indeed is a use case for saving that in a variable (though remote)

Comment: @BhargavRao - `in_file` is still in scope until the end of the function or module that contains the with statement, it doesn't go out of scope with the end of the `with` block - you can use it interchangeably with `file_obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Is remarkable that `with` works even if `return` or `sys.exit()` is called inside (that means `__exit__` is called anyway):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

class MyClass:
  def __enter__(self):
    print("Enter") 
    return self

  def __exit__(self, type, value, trace):
    print("type: {} | value: {} | trace: {}".format(type,value,trace))

# main code:
def myfunc(msg):
  with MyClass() as sample:
    print(msg)
    # also works if uncomment this:
    # sys.exit(0) 
    return

myfunc("Hello")
```

`return` version will show:

```
Enter
Hello
type: None | value: None | trace: None
```

`exit(0)` version will show:

```
Enter
Hello
type: <class 'SystemExit'> | value: 0 | trace: <traceback object at 0x7faca83a7e00>
```