# python: setup different config files for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, configuration, config

I am working on a personal project using python. Currently I am using nose for unit testing and there is a python file for storing all the settings, like files' paths, db config, etc.

Because the application will connect to a database, I hope when I do unit testing, the database used and the files the application reads/writes are not the ones storing all the real data.

I think a good way I could do is setting up several stages, but because I am using pure python without using any frameworks like Django, so I am not sure how to do that.

I can also write a simple script or something similar to switch between different config files before running unit tests/real work, but I think this way is not as good as setting up different stages.

Comment: Your Title is a bit misleading. You should maybe make it something like "using different configs for unit-tests". Also, reformatting your block of text with some practical examples would help make it easier to understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different avenues you can take here to help achieve what you are looking for.

To start, I strongly suggest looking at these two modules. I use these all the time for my unit testing.

[Mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) & [flexmock](https://has207.github.io/flexmock/)

If you really want to test against a database, you can make use of a context manager to set up a temporary database that will do your testing and once it is done it will destroy itself. For information on context managers, take a look at this to start you off:

[Stackoverflow - with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379147/understanding-the-python-with-statement)

With mocking, what you can do is in this case just mock out where you initially import your settings and use your unit-test version for settings.

Alternatively, you can also take a look at fixtures, which will help pre-set some data objects for you and you can test accordingly: [Fixtures](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fixtures)

Answer (score 2):

One working way to switch context to testing one is to store configs in files, so that they can be accessed with [ConfigArgParse](https://pypi.org/project/ConfigArgParse/). When you are launching the code in production mode you can use default config files location unless default location is redefined with environment variable:

```
import configargparse
import os 
config_location = os.getenv("MY_PROJECT_CONFIG_LOCATION", default="configs/production.yaml")
parser = configargparse.ArgParser(default_config_files=[config_location], ignore_unknown_config_file_keys=True)
```

When you are launching the code in test mode you can redefine default config file location using system environment variables:

```
class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def someTestMethod(self):
        os.environ['MY_PROJECT_CONFIG_LOCATION'] = 'configs/test.yaml'
        #any test code here
```