# use python context to override variable?

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm pretty sure I've seen this, but I can't get the syntax right.  I want to override a module "constant" during testing.  I can write the code like this:

```
import mymodule

try:
   hold = mymodule.FOO
   mymodule.FOO = 'test value'
   do_something()
finally:
   mymodule.FOO = hold
```

it seems to me that there should be a way to do this with a "with" statement, something like:

```
with mymodule.FOO = 'test value':
    do_something()
```

Is my mind deceiving me?  Is there a simple syntax to do what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the python keyword "with" used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)

Comment: I know, not "duplicate", but the assignment operator of `=` for the variable definition you want does not know how to reassign the constant after it is finished

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('mymodule.Foo', 'test value'):
    do_whatever()
```

If you're on a Python version prior to 3.3, `unittest.mock` doesn't exist, but there's a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) available on PyPI. You could also write your own context manager to do this. However, there is nothing to do this built into the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is called monkeypatching.

`unittest.mock` provides helper methods for this (as seen in another answer), but outside of the Python stdlib, I'd recommend looking at [`py.test`'s monkeypatching fixture](https://pytest.org/latest/monkeypatch.html):

```
def test_foo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('mymodule.FOO', 'test value')
    # more code here
    # ...

    # the monkeypatch is automatically reverted at the end of the test
```