# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new in Python and try to scrape data from the web to (eventually) feed a small database.

My code is generating a `NoneType` error. Could you assist?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    #1- create files to Leagues, stock data and error
FLeague= open("C:\Python\+exercice\SoccerLeague.txt","w")
FData=open("C:\Python\+exercice\FootballDump.txt","w")
ErrorFile=open("C:\Python\+exercice\ErrorFootballScrap.txt","w")
#Open the website
# 1- grab the data and get the error too
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.soccerstats.com/leagues.asp").read(),"html")
TableLeague =  soup.find("table", {"class" : "trow8"})
print TableLeague
#\here I just want to grab country name
for row in TableLeague("tr")[2:]:
       col = row.findAll("td")
# I try to identify errors
       try:
          country = col[1].a.string.stip()
          FLeague.write(country+"\n")
       except Exception as e:
          ErrorFile.write (country + ";" + str(e)+";"+str(col)+"\n")
          pass
    #close the files
FLeague.close
FData.close
ErrorFile.close
```

Comment: What is `stip()` in `col[1].a.string.stip()`?

Comment: @vaultah: It's probably a typo.  He probably means `strip()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
This includes code that reproduces the problem, and the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is coming from:

```
TableLeague("tr")[2:]
```

`TableLeague` is `None` here since there is no `table` element with `trow8` class. Instead use the `id` attribute to find the desired table element:

```
TableLeague = soup.find("table", {"id": "btable"})
```

Also, you probably meant `strip()` and not `stip()` here: `col[1].a.string.stip()`.

And, in order to close the files, call the `close()` method. Replace:

```
FLeague.close
FData.close
ErrorFile.close
```

with:

```
FLeague.close()
FData.close()
ErrorFile.close()
```

Or, even better, use [`with` context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for) to work with files - you would not need to close a file explicitly.