# python - Writing to csv file out of coroutine sink ... how to avoid closed file error?

Tags: python, csv, coroutine

My code (simplified):

```
import csv


def generate_record(downstream):
    try:
        while True:
            incoming = (yield)
            record = incoming.strip()
            for worker in downstream:
                worker.send(record)
    except GeneratorExit:
        for worker in downstream:
            worker.close()
        print('generate_record shutdown')


def file_writer(filename):
    l = list()    
    try:
        while True:
            record = (yield)
            l.append(record)
    except GeneratorExit:
        with open(filename, 'w', newline=''):
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(l)
        print('file_writer shutdown')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sink = file_writer('C:/Users/Some User/Downloads/data.csv')
    next(sink)    
    worker = generate_record([sink])
    next(worker)
    with open('C:/Users/Some User/Downloads/Energy.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            worker.send(line)
    worker.close()
```

Generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-43-ff97472f6399>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Some User/Documents/Python Scripts/isii.py', wdir='C:/Users/Some User/Documents/Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Users\Some User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Some User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Some User/Documents/Python Scripts/isii.py", line 75, in <module>
    worker.close()

  File "C:/Users/Some User/Documents/Python Scripts/isii.py", line 49, in generate_record
    worker.close()

  File "C:/Users/Some User/Documents/Python Scripts/isii.py", line 63, in file_writer
    writer.writerows(l)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

**What have I tried?**

I've tried incrementally writing with `writerow` within `file_writer` within the `try` block, but that generates the same error.

Comment: `worker.send(output)` seems to be typo of `worker.send(record)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `with` statement in the `file_writer` is missing `as f` part; by missing that, `f` references the global variable `f` instead which is closed at the time of writing; cases the `IOError`.

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
                                     ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `with open(filename) as f:`, it will do the operation you have added and then closes the file. So you don't need to use `worker.close()` since you are trying to close a file that already is closed.

See: [What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)

This should be a comment, but I do not seem to have enough reputation for that.

Comment: You still have to close the coroutine, though. Without that final worker.close, the coroutine stays open.