# In python why it won't print without newline

Tags: python

I am new to learning python. I don't understand why print command will output all variables on screen but write command to file only writes 2 first two variables.

```
print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'a+')

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")
line4 = line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3

# This command prints all 3 (line1,line2,line3) variables on terminal
print line4

#This command only writes line1 and line2 variables in file
target.write(line4)

print "close the file"
target.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

The OS normally flushes the write buffer after a newline.
When you `open(filename, 'a+')` the file, these same rules apply by default.

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer
>   size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive
>   value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes). A
>   negative buffering means to use the **system default, which is usually
>   line buffered** for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If
>   omitted, the system default is used.

Call `target.close()` to ensure everything is written out ("flushed") to the file (as per the comment below, close flushes for you). You can manually flush with `target.flush()`.

```
print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'a+')

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")
line4 = line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3

# This command prints all 3 (line1,line2,line3) variables on terminal
print line4

target.write(line4)

target.close() #flushes
```

Alternatively, using the `with` keyword will automatically close the file when we leave the `with` block: (see [What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for))

```
print "Opening the file..."
with open(filename, 'a+') as target:

   line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
   line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
   line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")
   line4 = line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3

   # This command prints all 3 (line1,line2,line3) variables on terminal
   print line4

   target.write(line4)
```

Comment: `close` autoflushes, so you usually don't need to `flush` yourself.

Comment: I think you should add a comment about `with`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already included close at the end but it still prints only line1 and line2 variable to file. Tried `with open(filename, 'a+') as target:` but same result. Can anyone explain this in layman.

Comment: Did you wait a couple seconds before checking the file? After you write/close, your guaranteed the OS has the full data to write to disk, but it may not actually write it out for a couple seconds.