# Pythonic way of finding regex match

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract first name from email address. The email format is `<first_name>@gmail.com`. If email is not matched return `None`. I've written the following python code

```
def getFirstName(email):
    email_re = re.compile(r'(\w+)@gmail.com')
    match = email_re.search(email)
    if match == None:
        return None
    return match.group(1)
```

The `None` checking part looks ugly. Can someone suggest better pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: `if match: return match.group(1)` will work. No other explicit returns are needed.

Comment: `return match.group(1) if match else None`

Comment: @PeterWood Nope. There is no need to `return None`: any python function always implicitly returns `None` if there are no explicit returns.

Comment: The code isn't the same as yours. It's checking `match` is not `None` before calling `group` on it, otherwise it's returning `None`. This is using Python's [ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator). Also, [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 1):

This *is* the Pythonic way of handling this. Well almost.

```
if match is None
```

Comment: Agreed. But, I was looking for an something other than `if` statement. Something like `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_first_name(email):
    match = re.search(r'(\w+)@gmail\.com', email)
    return match.group(1) if match else None
```

- You need to escape the `.` in your pattern or else it'll match anything.
- The [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369553/5971855) statement is not relevant here.