# How to open multiple files in Python by following a text list of filenames?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python code to perform some operations on a text file. I need to run this code over around 200+ text files that are all stored in the same folder.

I want the code to open one text file at a time, perform the operations and then start over with the next text file.

Can you give me some pointers regarding how I can do this?

My code is like this:

```
def main():
    text_file = open("filename.txt","r")
    #operations
    text_file.close()

main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in directory with extension .txt in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `listdir` to iterate through files.

```
import os

def main():
    for filename in os.listdir(somedir):
        filepath = os.path.join(somedir, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):  # Is filepath really a file, not a directory?
            text_file = open(filepath,"r")
            #operations
            text_file.close()

main()
```

As noted in the comments, it's better to use [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for).

Comment: btw. using a `with` statement instead of manually closing the file would probably be more pythonic and safe.

Answer (score -1):

not sure how many files you have but you could also look at 
http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/genfind.py and then send this to http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/genopen.py

this is the ideal solution for processing a lot of data..
Thanks Dave ;-)