# "with" keyword in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, with-statement

I came across this syntax for reading the lines in a file.

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

Say I wanted the `<do something with line>` line to append each line to a list. Is there any way to accomplish this, using the `with` keyword, in a list comprehension? Or, is there at least some way of doing what I want in a single statement?

Comment: you could do `[something(line) for line in open("foo.txt")]` but that wouldn't be using `with`

Comment: oneline: `with open("foo.txt") as f: result = [something(line) for line in open("foo.txt")]`

Comment: Just make sure you understand exactly [why `with` is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for).

Answer (score 4):

You can write something like

```
with open(...) as f:
    l = [int(line) for line in f]
```

but you can't put the `with` into the list comprehension.

It might be possible to write something like

```
l = [int(line) for line in open(...).read().split("\n")]
```

but you would need to call f.close() later manually and this way gives you no variable f. It might happen that the filhandle is closed automatically when going out of scope, but I would not rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

`with` uses a function as a context manager, so no.  `f` has no value until inside the block.  The best you could do is a 2 line implementation.

Comment: nope 1 line implementation works. But not one statement, I agree.

Comment: Fair enough--you're correct that I was referring to statements rather than lines.