# Python read text files written in columns into lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-3.6

A file `hoge.txt` which I want to read is as below

```
x1 y1 z1 
x2 y2 z2
x3 y3 z3
```

my code is now

```
lines = open('hoge.txt').readlines()
line_parts = [line.split() for line in lines]
x  = [float(v[0]) for v in line_parts]
y  = [float(v[0]) for v in line_parts]
z  = [float(v[0]) for v in line_parts]
```

Can I write this flow easier and simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you can do to improve on the source you mentioned. As a disclaimer, I'm assuming the x1, x2, etc... in your file are placeholders for numeric values, since otherwise you'd probably be better off without messing with a file at all. If that's a bad assumption, please let me know so I can edit my answer.

1. File objects are actually iterable, and there is no need to call `read()` or `readlines()`.
2. Use of a context manager with the keyword `with` allows you to ensure the file is closed when you're done with it.
3. I've always thought it was a neat trick that you could use `zip(*[...])` to transpose rows and columns.
4. Using multiple assignment, you can get the explicit `x`, `y`, and `z` variables you want.
5. The way the question was originally asked, `x`, `y`, and `z` would have had identical contents and ignored most of the file you were reading. Assuming this was undesired behavior, I fixed the bug.

In summary, you get the following source code:

```
with open('hoge.txt') as file:
    x, y, z = zip(*[[float(el) for el in line] for line in file])
```

It's probably worth mentioning that for just about anything you might want to do with that data, the module `pandas` is probably the tool you want to use. You could use the `read_csv()` function to read the file, and if you wanted the rows and columns transposed as in your example code, you could use the `.T` property on the resulting DataFrame object.

Additionally, part of the reason your code is verbose is that the file doesn't naturally align with how you want to use it. If you have such flexibility and don't need the file for anything else, a more natural format would be

```
x1 x2 x3
y1 y2 y3
z1 z2 z3
```

And then you could get away with slightly less verbose code.

```
with open('hoge.txt') as file:
    x, y, z = [[float(el) for el in line] for line in file]
```

Lastly, for simple typecasting of everything in a list, the `numpy` module is a joy to work with (after a medium learning curve) and admits the `astype()` method on its array objects. Alternatively, I find the `map()` function to be a little easier to read in such circumstances if you want to work with raw python lists. Since you're using Python 3, you would need to import `map()`.

```
from itertools import map

with open('hoge.txt') as file:
    x, y, z = zip(*[map(float, line) for line in file])
```

Comment: Nice answer! Nice catch that you could just do `for line in file` to get the lines. +1 There's a slight bug in your answer though. The value on each line of the OP's file is a _letter_ and a number. Thus, doing `float(el)` will fail. You'd need to do `float(el[1])` to explicit get the numerical part of the value.

Comment: Thanks! The way I'm reading it, I think x1, x2, etc... are placeholders for numeric values. Otherwise, he wouldn't need the file at all to grab those few floats. I've been wrong before though. What do you think he meant?

Comment: Well, to be honest @Hans, I'm not entirely sure. I just assumed that the values in the OP's file were literal. You could be right though, and they're simply placeholders. I guess we could just add notes to our answers stating our assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, the file contains columns for non-numeric values. Sorry for the ambiguity... Thank you for you guys comments and answer!!

Answer (score 3):

- You can use the [context manger statement `with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for).
- I'd actually question whether you need three separate variables to
  hold the values from each line. Just use a 2d list to hold the values
  from each line of your file.
- Your code has a slight bug. You need to access the `1`st index of each value in each line of your file.<sup>1</sup>

Here is your code with the above modifications:

```
with open('hoge.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    data = [[float(val[1]) for val in line.split()] for line in lines]
# ... use `data`
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'm assuming, of course, that the values in your file are ***not*** places-holders. If they are, then doing `float(val)` is all you need.</sub>