# in python 3.4, readline works fine alone, but dies in a 'with open' loop. Why?

Tags: python, file, io, with-statement

```
infile = 'xyz.txt'

f = open(infile)
line = f.readline() # these lines are all read fine 
print("line=",line)
line = f.readline()
print("line=",line)
line = f.readline()
print("line=",line)
pause()
f.close()

with open(infile) as f: 
    line = f.readline() # this reads the first line but
    print("line=",line) # dies without a message on line 2
    pause()
sys.exit

def pause():
    c = input("\nEnter q to quit, anything else to continue\n") 
    if (c.lower()=='q'): sys.exit()
    return (c)
```

Adding arguments to open, like 'r', 'ignore', encoding, etc. make no difference.

It happens on other input files as well, so it's not input specific.

It dies even without the pause in the loop

After the first line, it prints the line and the pause message,
and dies reading the second line.

Could this be a genuine compiler error?

Comment: There is no loop... what do you mean? Did you expect it to act like a loop?

Comment: `with open` is not a loop, `with` is a statement

Comment: As a side note, `sys.exit` doesn't do anything unless you call it.

Comment: Also, what does "dies" mean here? What actually happens? Does it just exit without a message? Raise an exception? Segfault? And there isn't any code that reads a second line, so where does this dying actually happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a loop to iterate over the lines:

```
import sys

def pause():
    c = input("\nEnter q to quit, anything else to continue") 
    if c.lower() == 'q': 
        sys.exit()

infile = 'ttest.csv'    #  <-- replace with your own file

with open(infile) as f: 
    for line in f:
        print('line = ', line)
        pause()
```

Comment: Don't suggest `readlines` on code that works perfectly fine without it; just `for line in f:`. There's no reason to read the whole file into memory and build a list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `with` (in this case `with open`) is not a loop, `with` is a statement (check out: [What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)) , so try this:

```
import sys
infile = 'xyz.txt'
def pause():
    c = input("\nEnter q to quit, anything else to continue\n") 
    return c
with open(infile,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      print("Current line:",line)
      d={'q':sys.exit}
      d.get(pause().lower(), lambda: '')()
sys.exit()
```

And you're asking the wrong question, readline also works fine with 'with open',

You're title was "in python 3.4, readline works fine alone, but dies in a 'with open' loop. Why?" as mentioned above `with` is not a loop