# Read lines from file and subsequently only write those lines to the file which don't contain a certain phrase

Tags: python, list, loops, file-io

I have one column list file:

```
$ cat test
blah
blahblah
blah22
bluh
blih
blihihih
```

All I want to is to remove `blah`-like lines. (Equivalent of bash `grep -v blah`.) So that `blah`, `blahblah` and `blah22` are removed.

I have this so far:

```
>>> f = open('test', 'rw+')
>>> line = f.readlines()
>>> for l in line:
...     if l.find('blah') == -1:
...             f.truncate(0)
...             f.write(l)
... 
>>> f.close()
```

I thought it would be fine, but after running this, from test file only this line is left:

```
$cat test
blihihih
```

How come, this has removed `blih` or `bluh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is best if you open the file first, and then write to it:

```
# open file
lines = open('test').readlines()

# over-write the file
with open('test', 'w') as out:
    for line in lines:
        if 'blah' not in line:
            out.write(line)
```

**Output** *(in test)*

```
bluh
blih
blihihih
```

Answer (score 2):

> How come, this has removed `blih` or `bluh`?

To answer your question, you truncate the file too often. Every call to `f.truncate(0)` will reset the file size to 0. Therefore only the last line `blihihih` will survive.

If you want to do it in one go:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r+')
lines = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for line in lines:
    if line.find('blah') < 0:
        f.write(line)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

Additionally, you should really use `with`:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        if line.find('blah') < 0:
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

(You won't need to write `f.close()` then. Read more about why using `with` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783672/1621041) for example.)