# Script to loop through and match files based on file name and append

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a directory with many files that are named like:

```
1234_part1.pdf
1234.pdf
5432_part1.pdf
5432.pdf
2323_part1.pdf
2323.pdf
etc.
```

I am trying to merge the pdf where the the first number part of the file are the same.
I have code that can do this one at a time, but when I have over 500 files in the directory I am not sure how to loop through, here is what I have so far:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
merger = PdfFileMerger()
merger.append(PdfFileReader(file('c:/example/1234_part1.pdf', 'rb')))
merger.append(PdfFileReader(file('c:/example/1234.pdf', 'rb')))
merger.write("c:/example/ouput/1234_combined.pdf")
```

Ideally the output file would be `'xxxx_combined_<today's date>.pdf'`.
i.e. `1234_combined_051719.pdf`

And also if there is a number file that only has part 1 or the other file it would not combined —
i.e. if there was a `9999_part1.pdf`, but no `9999.pdf`, then there would be no output for the `'9999_combined_<today's date>.pdf'`.

Comment: In order to provide the best answer, I need to know some more things.  1) Can we assume the numbers in the file name are always the same number of digits?  2) Will there only ever be 1 or 2 files with matching numbers, or could there be more?

Comment: Thanks, the numbers will always be 4 digits and be in the beginning of the file. There should always be 1 or 2 files with the same number

Comment: Hi @Lulumocha, is your question solved? If so, feel free to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `os.listdir()` to get all of the files in your directory Then use `.split()` at the end of your string (filename) to isolate the pdf file number. Then look for that number pattern in the list of files you made.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

dir = 'my/dir/of/pdfs/'
file_list = os.listdir(dir)
num_list = []

for fname in file_list:
    if '_' in fname:  # if the filename has an underscore in it
        file_num = fname.split('_')[0]  # get's first element in list of splits
    else:
        file_num = fname.split('.')[0]
    if file_num not in num_list:
        num_list.append(file_num)

# now you have a list of all of your file numbers you can grab all files
# in the file_list containing that number
for num in num_list:
    pdf_parts = [x for x in file_list if num in x] # grabs all files with that number
    if len(pdf_parts < 2):  # if there is only one pdf with that num ...
        continue  # skip it!
    # your pdf append operation here for each item in the pdf_parts list.
    # something like this maybe ...

    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    # sorts list by filename length in decending order so that 
    # '_part' files come first
    sorted_pdf_parts = pdf_parts.sort(key=len, reverse=True) 
    for part in sorted_pdf_parts:
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(dir + part, 'rb')))
    merger.write('out/dir/' + num + '_combined.pdf')
```

Comment: This is great, works perfectly.  Thank you. I added the datetime.datetime.now() into the merger.write and can get everything I need now.

Comment: It [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56193616/6282576) be done with only one `for loop` instead of three, which I believe is faster and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
from os import listdir
from datetime import datetime

file_names = listdir('D:\Code\python-examples\PDF')

for file_name in file_names:
    if "_" in file_name:
        digits = file_name.split('_')[0]
        if f'{digits}.pdf' in file_names:
            with open(f'{digits}.pdf', 'rb') as digit_file, open(f'{digits}_part1.pdf', 'rb') as part1_file:
                merger = PdfFileMerger()
                merger.append(PdfFileReader(part1_file))
                merger.append(PdfFileReader(digit_file))
                merger.write(f'{digits}_combined_{datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%y")}.pdf')
```

A couple of notes:

- It's recommended to use [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369553/6282576) when *opening* files.
- You can use `datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%y")` to get the date format you mentioned.

So if we have a folder like this:

[image: initial folder]

After we run the code, we have:

[image: done]

And we can see that it works:

[image: works]

I also uploaded the code, along with relevant files, to my [GitHub page](https://github.com/amirashabani/python-examples/tree/master/PDF). If anyone wants to try it themselves, they can check it out.