# can't figure out writing to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I can't get the output I have scraped using Beautiful Soup to write to a CSV file. I have it in the format but I like when I print, but cannot get it to write to a csv like that.

I've tried several variations of the csv write function but most of the things I can find online are for a given list or dictionary, none of which is the format of my data. Maybe I need to make it a list somehow?

```
rank = (pga_text)[0]
player = (pga_text)[2]
sg_p = (pga_text)[4]
pga_file = rank + ", " + player + ", " + sg_p
print(pga_file)

myfile = open(r'C:\Users\Walsh\Documents\Python Scripts\pga.csv', 'w')
with myfile:
    myfields = [rank]
writer = csv.writer(myfile)
writer.writerow(pga_file)
a.close()
```

As mentioned, the output from the print is in the format I wanted:

```
1, Justin Harding, 1.000
2, Andrew Putnam, .952
3, Dominic Bozzelli, .821
4, Graeme McDowell, .789
```

but nothing writes to the actual file.

Comment: fixed the indentation

Comment: What is the variable "a" that you use a.close(), is this a typo?

Comment: There's no need to put variables in parentheses like `(pga_text)[0]`. Just write `pga_text[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the variable and parentheses. That's been fixed. The a.(close) is probably a typo at this point. I've been trying to diagnose with several different code types. I can change that to myfile.close in the example to actually close the file. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this example it appears as though you are writing the string pga_file.

You want to write a row as a list type.

```
rank = (pga_text)[0]
player = (pga_text)[2]
sg_p = (pga_text)[4]
pga_file = [rank, player, sg_p]
print(pga_file)

myfile = open(r'C:\Users\Walsh\Documents\Python Scripts\pga.csv', 'w')
with myfile:
    myfields = [rank]
writer = csv.writer(myfile)
writer.writerow(pga_file)
a.close()
```

In this example it also appears as though you are not using myfields.

See: [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) documentation

Comment: Fix the indentation

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the `with`.

`with` will clean up its associated resources when execution flow exits `with` scope. That's to say, in your orignal code, when you called `writer.writerow(pga_file)`, the file associated with `with` had been closed. Try something like this:

```
import csv

pga_file = '1, Justin Harding, 1.000'
myfile = open(r'pga.csv', 'w')
with myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(pga_file)
```

Regarding to `with`, you may refer to [what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for).

Answer (score 0):

I you dont want to import csv library, you can do this way also

```
rank = 1
player = "Justin Harding"
sg_p = 1.000
pga_file = str(rank) + ", " + player + ", " + str(sg_p) + "\n"

myfile = open('pga.csv', 'w')
myfile.write(pga_file)
myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have the string you want to write to the csv file, you could use this helper method. (Given that pga_file is of string type). I've used this simple writer with different extensions and just tested it out with csv files and it worked.

```
def save (filename, pga_file):
  f = open(filename, 'w')
  f.write(pga_file)
  f.close()
```

where filename is 'C:\Users\Walsh\Documents\Python Scripts\pga.csv'

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

f = open('test.csv', mode='w')

with f as test_file:
    test_writer = csv.writer(test_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    test_writer.writerow(['John', 'Smith', 'November'])
    test_writer.writerow(['Frank', 'Mueller', 'March'])

print('file created')
```

does this test code  work in your environment?