# Checking if the first cell of a CSV is blank in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to write a dictionary to a CSV. It's in a loop so each iteration through the loop should append the latest dictionary to the end of my CSV.

I wanted to add a feature where I only write the header to the CSV if the file is blank.

I've tried to use `f.tell()` to check if it's in the first position but it doesn't seem to be consistent. I delete everything and set the cursor to the first cell and save the file and it'll return 2 sometimes and 0 others.

I was thinking of changing the data to a list like this so I can just do `data[1][0]`:

```
data=list(csv.reader(csvDataFile))
```

and then using an if statement to see if the first position is empty but that feels inefficient (if it's not, then just let me know and I'll stick with that). This is code snippet here. Is there a more efficient  and clear way to do this?

```
with open('DataOutput.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, sorted_closes.keys())
    print(f.tell())
    if f.tell() == 0:
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(sorted_closes)
    else:
        writer.writerow(sorted_closes)
```

**My Solution:**

In case anyone encounters the same problem. I ended up just using a try/except to handle the case where the file was empty.

Because `newline=''` would (for some reason) start my output on line 2. None of these proposed methods worked. If I looked for the row beginning at line 2 in an empty file, it would throw an `IndexError`. If i tried the `csv.Sniffer.has_header` approach, it would never return `True` because the header was always on line 2.

Anyway, this eventually worked for me. Not sure if its the most efficient way but it worked:

```
    with open(filename + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_a, open(filename + '.csv','r', newline='') as csv_r:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_r)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_a, dict.keys())
        data = [row for row in reader]

        try:
            first_row_blank = True if data[1] == [] else False

        except IndexError:
            first_row_blank = True

        if first_row_blank:
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(dict)
        else:
            writer.writerow(dict)
```

Comment: I think you should use the pandas library.

Comment: can you share a testable fragment of `'DataOutput.csv'` ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes. If it was just created or if I decide to clear out all the data and start over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work:

```py
with open('some_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_a, open('some_file.csv','r') as csv_r:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_r)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_a, sorted_closes.keys())
    data = [row for row in reader] #turns all the cells into a list
    if data[0][0]=='':
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(sorted_closes)
        # or whatever you want to do if the first cell is empty
    else:
        writer.writerow(sorted_closes)
        # or whatever you want to do if the first cell is NOT empty
```

Comment: i already have a with open('some_file.csv', 'a') as f. So that I can append. Are you suggesting that I start with your code and in the #code for first cell empty would get the second open() statement to append? Seems a little inefficient

Comment: With the csv library you can only do one function at a time on an open file, so you either have to open the file with append permissions later or do as the edit above and have two open statements at once.

Comment: i think im going to go with this answer, however. I keep getting this error:    if data[0][0]==' ':
IndexError: list index out of range. If I just make it data[0] in (None, "", " ") it wont trigger the if statement. I've printed the data to check and indeed the first entry of the list is a []

Comment: I suppose you could try throwing in an extra if statement before the if data[0][0]=='': statement. Something like, if row: if data[0][0]=='':.... This should only run if there is a first row to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is probably to try to read the first row:

```
has_headers = True
# Assumes the file exists
with open('DataOutput.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    try:
        headers = next(reader)
    except StopIteration:
        has_headers = False
# Open in append mode and add headers if necessary
```

Alternatively, if you delete the file rather than just clearing it out, you could could try to create it and write the headers each time.

```
try: 
    # Open in exclusive creation mode
    with open('DataOutput.csv', 'x') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

with open('DataOutput.csv', 'a') as f:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. It worked for me

```
 with open('dataFile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvReader:
            if row[0] in (None, ""):
                -- TODO for empty
```

Comment: I tried that but got this error:     for row in reader:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: I think it's because I need to append so I already have an ( with open('DataOutput.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:). Do you mind showing me how that would work with my current code?

Comment: Take new line as \n then you already have opened document so read as CSV.reader, I think you can access your cell.