# How to get current run_id inside of mlflow.start_run()?

Tags: python, mlflow

`mlflow.active_run()` returns nothing so I can't just use
`current_rui_id = mlflow.active_run().info.run_id`

I have to get **run_id** inside of this construction for being able to continue logging parameters,  metrics and artifacts inside of another block but for the same model:

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="test_ololo"):

    """ 
       fitting a model here ...
    """

    for name, val in metrics:
        mlflow.log_metric(name, np.float(val))

    # Log our parameters into mlflow
    for k, v in params.items():
        mlflow.log_param(key=k, value=v)

    pytorch.log_model(learn.model, f'model')
    mlflow.log_artifact('./outputs/fig.jpg')
```

I have to get current **run_id** to continue training inside the same run

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_id="215d3a71925a4709a9b694c45012988a"):

    """
       fit again
       log_metrics
    """

    pytorch.log_model(learn.model, f'model')
    mlflow.log_artifact('./outputs/fig2.jpg')
```

Answer (score 11):

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="test_ololo") as run:

    run_id = run.info.run_id
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain how it helps and what the code does.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this code snippet:

```
import mlflow
mlflow.start_run()
run = mlflow.active_run()
print("Active run_id: {}".format(run.info.run_id))
mlflow.end_run()
```

Comment: Bonus: One should use `mlflow.start_run()` inside a `with`-block so that it is "cleaned up" if an error occurs and it does not reach `end_run()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for

Answer (score 5):

The above should work and is in fact the best way to get a hold of active run inside of the with `mlflow.start_run()` block.

For completeness, `mlflow.active_run().info.run_id` will also work if executed inside of the `with` block. The `with` block will end mlflow run on exit, so there is no active run once the block exited.