# Is there a benefit to use the "with dag as DAG(...)" clause to create a DAG

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I create my Airflow DAGs as follows:

```
dag = DAG(...)
```

But in multiple tutorials and course I see that they use the `with ... as` clause like this:

```
with DAG(...) as dag:
    # Code that will use the dag variable.
```

I guess this way, the DAG instances will be destroyed after the scheduler executes the code block, but is there a real benefit in doing so? I can't find any documentation talking about this.

Comment: You can see what `__enter__` and `__exit__` do in the source code: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see that the the dag is pushed to a dag context manager, which seems to be some kind of collection. Does that mean are supposed to use the "with ... as " clause when creating a dag ?

Comment: Reason is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369553/10981911)

Comment: I understand what the  "with as" clause do but I was rather asking the impact on airflow ecosystem.

Comment: One little advantage is that you don't have to type in each task dag=dag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

If you understand what `with...as` does, then you should understand that its impact on the airflow ecosystem is really no different.

Specifically, it ensures that unmanaged resources -in this case implementations of the DAG class- are properly cleaned up, even if there are exceptions thrown (without needing to use a try/except block every time.)

Additionally it's nice to not have to add `dag=dag` to every single one.

Comment: What actually needs to be cleaned up, though? `with` is used a lot to make sure that open file handles are automatically closed, for example. What would an Airflow DAG need to make sure was cleaned up?