# Difference between reading a csv file and a text file?

Tags: python

What is the point of

```
with open('grades.csv', 'r') as csvfile
```

in this code ????

```
import csv

with open('grades.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    grades_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    row_num = 1
    for row in grades_reader:
        print('Row #{}:'.format(row_num), row)
        row_num += 1
```

?? becuase when I rewrite the code again as:

```
import csv
grades_reader=open('grades.csv', 'r')
row_num = 1
for row in grades_reader:
    print('Row #{}:'.format(row_num), row)
    row_num += 1
```

I get the same result but without the output being a list. So is it safe to assume that with command will turn it to a list when read?

Comment: You should prefer to use with() as that'll close the file and prevent resource leaks, but as answered, that's not the root cause here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about `with open('grades.csv', 'r') as csvfile:` line.
It's about `grades_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')` in the first case.

In the first case, you are using the `csv.reader`, so it returns a list.
In the second case, you're just reading the file as text.

You can change the second case as, to get the same result as the first case

```
import csv
grades_reader=open('grades.csv', 'r')
grades_reader = csv.reader(grades_reader, delimiter=',')
row_num = 1
for row in grades_reader:
    print('Row #{}:'.format(row_num), row)
    row_num += 1
```

Here are few discussions that you can find that talks about python's `with` statement
[What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for)
[What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)