# "str cannot be interpreted as int" while trying to open a file

Tags: python, file

I'm wondering why I get an error while trying to open a file in a tkinter button function.

```
def manage():
    output_file = os.open("Prices.txt", "w")
    output_file.write(",".join(HEADERS)+"\n")
    output_file.close()
```

Here is the simplified function, I get an error on the second line.
The thing is it works just fine when I run it as is.
However I had to convert it in a `.exe` to be able to run on computers without python, I've done it with `pyinstaller` and that maybe is the cause of the problem (not 100% sure tho).

Comment: [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) is not the same as the builtin [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). It looks like you mean to be using the latter. You probably also want to use a [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1369526/11082165) instead of calling `close` manually: `with open("Prices.txt", "w") as output_file:`

Comment: @Flimm `os.open` expects a path as its first argument. You might be thinking of `os.fdopen`. The error is because the second argument (the flags) needs to be an integer.

Comment: I'd also suggest the study of the `pathlib` module, which also offers ways to open files.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly with how you created the `exe` file; update your question with the relevant details.

Comment: You really need a [mcve]; all you've shown is a function definition with no call, which won't produce any errors.