# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not create socket: Too many open files

Tags: python, flask, psycopg2

I am running a flask application on default development server. I have defined a post method which push data from an IoT device every few seconds to postgres database. I am making sure all the DB connections opened are also closed successfully. The only issue I am having is that I am getting error - too many open files.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/aqi/add', methods=['POST'])
def addAQI():

   ## get a connection from the pool
   conn = get_db_connection()
   cur = conn.cursor()

   if request.method == 'POST':

       data = request.form

       co_ugm3 = data.get('co', default=0)
       no2_ugm3 = data.get('no2', default=0)
       so2_ugm3 = data.get('so2', default=0)
       o3_ugm3 = data.get('o3', default=0)
       co2_ugm3 = data.get('co2', default=0)
       tvoc = data.get('tvoc', default=0)
       pm1_ugm3 = data.get('pm1', default=0)
       pm25_ugm3 = data.get('pm25', default=0)
       pm4_ugm3 = data.get('pm4', default=0)
       pm10_ugm3 = data.get('pm10', default=0)
       noise_dba = data.get('noise', default=0)
       datetime = data.get('datetime')
       h2s_ugm3 = data.get('h2s', default=0)
       station_name = data.get('station')
       battery_voltage_dc = data.get('battery', default=0)
       temperature_celsius = data.get('tmp', default=0)
       relative_humidity_percent = data.get('hr', default=0)
       barometric_pressure_hpa = data.get('hpa', default=0)
       station_id = data.get('station_id')

       # if device_id != None and coordenadas != None and registrada != None:
       try: 
          cur.execute("INSERT INTO nifx_devices_data(co_ugm3, no2_ugm3, so2_ugm3, o3_ugm3,   co2_ugm3, tvoc, pm1_ugm3, pm25_ugm3, pm4_ugm3, pm10_ugm3, noise_dba, datetime, h2s_ugm3, station_name, battery_voltage_dc, temperature_celsius, relative_humidity_percent, barometric_pressure_hpa,station_id) VALUES('"+str(co_ugm3)+"','"+str(no2_ugm3)+"','"+str(so2_ugm3)+"','"+str(o3_ugm3)+"','"+str(co2_ugm3)+"','"+str(tvoc)+"','"+str(pm1_ugm3)+"','"+str(pm25_ugm3)+"','"+str(pm4_ugm3)+"','"+str(pm10_ugm3)+"','"+str(noise_dba)+"','"+str(datetime)+"','"+str(h2s_ugm3)+"','"+str(station_name)+"','"+str(battery_voltage_dc)+"','"+str(temperature_celsius)+"','"+str(relative_humidity_percent)+"','"+str(barometric_pressure_hpa)+"','"+str(station_id)+"')")

          conn.commit()
          data = {'Status': 1}
          response = Response(response=json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
          response.status_code = 200
       except Exception as e:
          cur.execute('rollback')
          print(e)
          data = {'Status': 0}
          response = Response(response=json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
          response.status_code = 400
            
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return response
```

I have also configured pgbouncer for connection pooling.

Here is the complete error msg:
[image]

```
def get_db_connection():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="database",
                            port="port",
                            host="ipaddress",
                            user="username",
                            password="password",
                            cursor_factory= psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    return conn
```

Comment: To your question add the complete error message.

Comment: i have updated my question with complete error message

Comment: 1) Do not use images for textual information copy and paste as text. 2) The issue seems to be coming from `get_db_connection`. Add that code to your question.

Comment: this error comes after every few days, so i just took a snapshot. i will copy complete text when it shows again.

Comment: btw when i restart flask service, the error disappears for a few days

Comment: I am not seeing where you are using the `psycopg2` [pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html?highlight=pool#module-psycopg2.pool).

Comment: i am using pgbouncer. https://www.pgbouncer.org/usage.html

Comment: My advice at this point is to monitor [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW), the Postgres log and  `ps ax` on the Flask machine. Something is not cleaning up after itself and it is going to take more digging to figure out what.

Comment: If it works a few days and then breaks after that time, it means that *somewhere in your code*, you are leaking database connections or any other *file like* object.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i have monitored pg_stat_activity but the number of sessions doesn't exceeds 9 or 10.. which means connection pooling is working.
Also what do i look for in ps ax?

Comment: Start with `ps ax | postgres`.

Comment: Besides postgres, the problem could be also from pgbouncer, did you check the logs from it?

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix system, a connection is a "file like" object. You could be hitting the terminal's file limit. This limit can be verified using
`ulimit -n`. (usually defaults to 1024).

It can be increased by using `ulimit -n 4096`. This increases the limit of that terminal session to `4096` and does not affect other terminal sessions.

Based on one of your comments "btw when i restart flask service, the error disappears for a few days", this could be the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use `with` statements instead of `open` or `close`. As the error message states too many open files. Please refer this question on how to use with statement.

[What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)

Comment: i am creating database connections so i am not sure how does this answers my question.

Comment: Did you try using the with statement? The error method clears states there are too many connection opened and is not able to create a new.

Comment: This does not answer the question nor does it explain why the error occurs in the first place. The OP clearly closes the connection in their code.