# Error using pyvirtualcam: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, pyvirtualcam

I am trying to fix my webcam, that has a horizontal green line in it, using OpenCV to inpaint the line and pyvirtualcam to create a virtual cam and use it in apps like discord and google meet.
The image processing with OpenCV is working correctly, but I am getting te following error trying to create the virtual cam:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\webcamfix\camfix.py", line 37, in <module>     
    cam.send(frame)
  File "...\pyvirtualcam\camera.py", line 349, in send
    self._backend.send(frame)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
import pyvirtualcam
from pyvirtualcam import PixelFormat

# Read webcam
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Set width to 1280 and height to 720
webcam.set(3, 1280)
webcam.set(4, 720)

# Read mask
mask = cv2.imread('mask.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Start virtual cam with 1280x720 30fps
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(1280, 720, 30, fmt=PixelFormat.BGR) as cam:
    print('Virtual camera device: ' + cam.device)


if webcam.isOpened():
    sucess, frame = webcam.read()
    while sucess:
        sucess, frame = webcam.read()

        # Inpainting frame where mask limits using TELEA technique
        frame = cv2.inpaint(frame, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
        
        # Fliping image
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

        # Displaying video and closing the window if ESC is pressed
        cv2.imshow("webcamfix", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if key == 27: # ESC
            break

        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
```

As pyvirtualcam documentation recommends, I am using OBS virtual camera and Unity Video Capture. If there is some easier way to create a virtual camera with python on windows I would be glad to know.

Comment: in a proper [mre], you could have stripped out all the OpenCV code and still reproduce the issue. please review that article thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `with` ... `as cam` statement, the `cam` object is automatically closed after the nested block of code.

`cam` object applies the same behaviour as [opening a file using with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783672/4926757) (the file is automatically closed after the nested block of code).

Since the `cam` object is closed we are getting an exception *"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'"*.

---

Replace `with pyvirtualcam.Camera(1280, 720, 30, fmt=PixelFormat.BGR) as cam:` with:

```
cam = pyvirtualcam.Camera(1280, 720, 30, fmt=PixelFormat.BGR)
```

---

Alternatively, place the code after `with pyvirtualcam.Camera(1280, 720, 30, fmt=PixelFormat.BGR) as cam` inside the nested block:

```
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(1280, 720, 30, fmt=PixelFormat.BGR) as cam:
    print('Virtual camera device: ' + cam.device)

    if webcam.isOpened():
        success = True
        while success:
            success, frame = webcam.read()
            
            # Displaying video and closing the window if ESC is pressed
            if success:
                # Inpainting frame where mask limits using TELEA technique
                frame = cv2.inpaint(frame, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
            
                # Flipping image
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
                
                cv2.imshow("webcamfix", frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == 27: # ESC
                    break

                cam.send(frame)
                cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
```